# Passing parameters to a report in SSRS but no report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I can run the query in management studio and it runs fine, but when I try to run it in ssrs 2008, or pass the parameters from an MVC app, no report.  I am guessing there is some kind of issue with my report parameter settings but I cant see it.

query:

```
SELECT p.PersonId, p.FirstName + ' ' +  p.LastName as Name, p.FirstName, p.Address, p.City, p.State, p.Zip, l.BodyText, l.CreatedBy
FROM Person p Join Letter l on p.personid = l.personid
where l.PersonId = @PersonId
and l.letterid = @LetterId
```

Parameter settings: @PersonId & @LetterID are both integers, no default value, internal.

link from the app:

```
("http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Trespass/Letter&rs:Command=Render&PersonId=" + PersId + "&LetterId=" + LetterId);
```

When clicked, it renders this url:

```
http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Trespass/Letter&rs:Command=Render&PersonId=60&LetterId=22
```

which looks good to me.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you *sure* they're **internal** parameters? By definition, internal parameters must have a default, though this can be `null`. Though if they are internal, that explains why they're not working - internal parameters cannot be affected by a URL at all.

Comment: When you paste your url in browser does that work? `http://MyServer/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/Trespass/Letter&rs:Command=Render&PersonId=60&LetterId=22`

Comment: @Ian Preston - Thankyou, your comment led me to the solution which that my parameters should have been hidden, not internal.  All is working swimmingly now.  Throw up and answer so I can mark it answered.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @teahou! Seemed like a good chance that was the issue, but only a guess so hence just the comment. Added as answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment, it seems like the parameters were **Internal** when they should've been **Hidden** only.

[Creating Report Parameters and Setting Report Parameter Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337234%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) explains why:

> You can set options that control parameter visibility in the published
>   report. Setting the Hidden and Internal options provides different
>   levels of visibility. You can hide the parameter on the parameter
>   input area of the published report, yet set values for it on a report
>   URL or in a subscription definition. If you set a parameter to
>   Internal, it is not exposed in any way except in the report
>   definition. An internal parameter must have a default value, which can
>   be null if the Allow null value option has been selected.